# Is there a better way to load in a big animation?

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl, sdl-image

Maybe not really big, but a hundred frames or something. Is the only way to load it in by making an array and loading each image individually?

load_image() is a function I made which loads the images and converts their BPP.

```
expl[0] = load_image( "explode1.gif" );
expl[1] = load_image( "explode2.gif" );
expl[2] = load_image( "explode3.gif" );
expl[3] = load_image( "explode4.gif" );
...
expl[99] = load_image( "explode100.gif" );
```

Seems like their should be a better way.. at least I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique is spritesheets, in which a single, large image is divided into a grid of cells, with each cell containing one frame of an animation.  Often, all animation frames for any game entity are placed on a single, sometimes huge, sprite sheet.

Comment: This is probably the best way in the long run, if the amount of frames is quite large (say over, 15)

Comment: I was considering sprites, but I wasn't sure if they were still the best way since I would have to iterate through and cut out SDL_Surface. So this is still a good way of doing something that has.. let's say 50 frames of animation?

Comment: Fundamentally, something is iterating over the data in the animation.  The SDL_BlitSurface function makes this very efficient.  I've seen this technique used to blit sprites with more than 200 frames.  There's no particular reason you couldn't use even more.

Answer (score 1):

maybe simplify your loading with a utility function that builds a filename for each iteration of a loop:

```
LoadAnimation(char* isFileBase, int numFrames)
{
    char szFileName[255];
    for(int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++)
    {
       // append the frame number and .gif to the file base to get the filename
       sprintf(szFileName, "%s%d.gif", isFileBase, i);
       expl[i] = load_image(szFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll probably use this for this first program I'm making.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading as a grid, stack all the frames in one vertical strip (same image).  Then you only need to know how many rows per frame and you can set a pointer to the frame row offset. You end up still having contiguous scan lines that can be displayed directly or trivially chewed off into separate images.